# Shows Deprecated error in wampserver

Tags: php, sql, deprecated

I have been trying to show some results from an MySQL database, which has more than 5000 lines.

I have tried with 10 lines, the code works, but it shows warning like in the screenshot!!

Shows error in wampserver

Shows almost same error in online server as well
Please help me to fix it , I have no knowledge in SQL.

[image: Error]

```
    <?php
    class DBController
    {
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user = "user";
        private $password = "1234";
        private $database = "new1";



        function __construct()
        {
            $conn = $this->connectDB();
            if (!empty($conn)) {
                $this->selectDB($conn);
            }
        }

        function connectDB()
        {
            $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
            return $conn;
        }

        function selectDB($conn)
        {
            mysql_select_db($this->database, $conn);
        }

        function runQuery($query)
        {
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
            }
            if (!empty($resultset))
                return $resultset;
        }

        function numRows($query)
        {
            $result   = mysql_query($query);
            $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Please check it

```
<?php
    function perpage($count, $per_page = '10',$href) {
        $output = '';
        $paging_id = "link_perpage_box";
        if(!isset($_POST["page"])) $_POST["page"] = 1;
        if($per_page != 0)
        $pages  = ceil($count/$per_page);
        if($pages>1) {

            if(($_POST["page"]-3)>0) {
                if($_POST["page"] == 1)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=1 class="current-page">1</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="1" />';
            }
            if(($_POST["page"]-3)>1) {
                    $output = $output . '...';
            }

            for($i=($_POST["page"]-2); $i<=($_POST["page"]+2); $i++)    {
                if($i<1) continue;
                if($i>$pages) break;
                if($_POST["page"] == $i)
                    $output = $output . '<span id='.$i.' class="current-page" >'.$i.'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="' . $i . '" />';
            }

            if(($pages-($_POST["page"]+2))>1) {
                $output = $output . '...';
            }
            if(($pages-($_POST["page"]+2))>0) {
                if($_POST["page"] == $pages)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=' . ($pages) .' class="current-page">' . ($pages) .'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="' . $pages . '" />';
            }

        }
        return $output;
    }

    function showperpage($sql, $per_page = 10, $href) {     
        $result  = mysqli_query($sql);
        $count   = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $perpage = perpage($count, $per_page,$href);
        return $perpage;
    }

?>
```

[image: err]

Comment: **Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. That library existed a lot of years ago and is now deprecated.** Kindly use either `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: This is not about SQL, but the PHP Programming Language and the implementations being used. `:(` You need to migrate the whole code to the new version.

Comment: Can anyone give me a new code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, taking the risk myself and answering the migrated code. Make sure you have **MySQLi** installed by checking with `phpinfo();`. Your new code:

```
<?php
    class DBController
    {
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user = "user";
        private $password = "1234";
        private $database = "new1";
        private $conn;

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
            if (!empty($conn)) {
                $this->selectDB($conn);
            }
        }

        function connectDB()
        {
            $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
            return $conn;
        }

        function runQuery($query)
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
            }
            if (!empty($resultset))
                return $resultset;
            return false;
        }

        function numRows($query)
        {
            $result   = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($this->conn, $result);
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Notes:**

1. New private variable `$conn`.
2. Now there's no `select_db()` function.
3. Added better `return` for `runQuery`.

**Reason:** [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/462627)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hah .. I'm glad to know you ... I have a lot of codes which need to be update to new version .. Can I paste them for you and you convert them for me ? `:-P` *(just kidding)*

Comment: @Shafizadeh Oh yea, well, please use my `Auto-PHP-MySQL-to-MySQLi-er` function! `:D`

Comment: I think that worked , there are some other error , but I can work with them . Thanks

Comment: @ArchanaP Let me know if there's any issues.

Comment: Actually there is , can u help me with one more code ? The "Deprecated" error gone , but shows an error from another php file in index.php. (Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\test\perpage.php on line 45) . May I post the code here ?

Comment: @ArchanaP First parameter should be the connection object. Kindly give that. `:)`

Comment: @ArchanaP I guess that would be a new question. But how can you have `[<?php`? Looks like an array!

Comment: @Praveen Kumar , I have posted the script with my main question . Kindly check . You are being helpful . Thank you.

Comment: @ArchanaP See my comments above.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, [<?php? that came when I pate it here , my bad

Comment: @ArchanaP [edit] the post, delete the new content from `[<?php` and add your content again.

Comment: @ArchanaP I rolled back to however it was before, now paste the new contents just after the last line.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, it took some time !!! Please check it ... Error screen shot atatched

Comment: @ArchanaP Change `$result  = mysqli_query($sql);` to `$result  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`. I assume `$conn` to hold the connection object, else recreate it using `$conn = mysqli_connect...`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, may i send you the full script ? in zip ?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, I have copied it , I will send you the full script including database . Thanks

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, Please check your mail

Comment: @ArchanaP Gotcha... `:)`

Comment: @ArchanaP Working on it.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, `:-(`